# ag-grid pivot total columns open by default

Tags: pivot, ag-grid

I have pivot tables in ag-grid which I have enabled `gridOptions.pivotColumnGroupTotals = after`.
But the default setting is for the group total collapse the other values.

Is there way to make this grouped total start open by default?

Ideally I could specify which column should be opened by default.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use `openByDefault` property, while declaring your column group object, resulting in these groups appearing as open by default..

here is an example code snippet.

```
    //column group 'Performance'
    headerName: 'Performance',
    groupId: 'performance',
    openByDefault : true, //this tells AG grid to expand the children by default
    children: [
        {
            headerName: "Bank Balance", field: "bankBalance", width: 180, editable: true,
            filter: 'winningsFilter',
            valueFormatter: currencyFormatter,
            type: 'numericColumn',
            cellClassRules: {
                'currencyCell': 'typeof x == "number"'
            },
            enableValue: true,
            // colId: 'sf',
            // valueGetter: '55',
            // aggFunc: 'sum',
            icons: {
                sortAscending: '<i class="fa fa-sort-amount-up"/>',
                sortDescending: '<i class="fa fa-sort-amount-down"/>'
            }
        },
        {
            colId: 'extraInfo1',
            headerName: "Extra Info 1", columnGroupShow: 'open', width: 150, editable: false, filter: false,
            sortable: false, suppressMenu: true, cellStyle: { "text-align": "right" },
            cellRenderer: function() {
                return 'Abra...';
            }
        },
        {
            colId: 'extraInfo2',
            headerName: "Extra Info 2", columnGroupShow: 'open', width: 150, editable: false, filter: false,
            sortable: false, suppressMenu: true, cellStyle: { "text-align": "left" },
            cellRenderer: function() {
                return '...cadabra!';
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep, thanks for your answer, but that doesn't work for my case unfortunately. In order to use `openByDefault` you need to have your columns specified individually like in your snipped - which is not the case for a pivot structure.

I've made to make it by calling some methods provided by the grid api after the grid is opened - but I don't think it's a great solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

see here:

https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/pivoting/#expandable-pivot-column-groups

in python, this would open to the 4th level, i think -1 sets all open:

```html
  dag.AgGrid(
                            dashGridOptions={
                                             "pivotDefaultExpanded" : 4,
                            })
```